# Running Applet on struts project

Tags: jsp, struts2, applet, jnlp

I'm working on Struts 2 framework. And I had to go to Applet for recording audio on a web page, since it shouldn't use flash for it. I've done a java applet class and exported as a executable jar file through eclipse. When I first try directly through applet tag it shown permission denied error. Then after searching I found to use jnlp for accessing. My jnlp and jar file both are in Webroot folder. When I add jnlp_href param to applet tag I not getting the applet interface on my jsp. The JNLP configuration as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp href="recorderApplet.jnlp">
<information>
  <title>Recorder Applet</title>
  <vendor>Ram</vendor>
</information>
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.6+" />
  <jar href="elgg.jar" main="true" />
</resources>
<applet-desc
  name="Recorder Applet"
  width="350"
  height="150"
  main-class="RecorderUI">
</applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

And Applet Tag as follows....

```
<applet code="RecorderUI.class" archive="elgg.jar">
        <param name="jnlp_href" value="recoderApplet.jnlp">
    </applet>
```

And when i directly try to download jnlp file as follows , I'm able to download...

```
<a href="recoderApplet.jnlp">JNLP</a>
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: JNLP used to download and execute Java Program not the Applet.